# Как разместить один TextView слева, а второе текстовое поле - справа на Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Как сделать так, чтобы в одном и том же LinearLayout 2 разных TextView были "притянуты" к разным краям экрана - один к левому, другой к правому? Установка параметра android:layout_gravity="left/right" не помогает.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/ololo">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"

                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"

                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ololo">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView6" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/textView7" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант 2:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ololo">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView6" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/textView7" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант 3:

```
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ololo">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

см. картинку 2.